# opencv DMatch imgIdx is greater than the size of the training set

Tags: c++, opencv, flann

I have 1000 patterns (images I wish to look up on a particular scene), my current algorithm gets the descriptors for each pattern, stored them in a vector and use that vector to train FlannBasedMatcher.

If I do a knnMatch with k = 3 I get matches with an imgIdx > 1000, that's the reason for this question (I tried k = 2 and have the same problem), I couldn't find anything about this, could someone give me a hand with this?.

UPDATE : I was adding two times the patterns descriptors, that's why I was getting imgIdx above 1000, now the problem I have is that with `k == 2` I get one match with distance 0 and one with > 0, the distance ratio is 0 and my theory is that I'm getting distance 0 because the pattern matching is exactly the same as the scene, but when I do this without training I'm not getting distance 0, any idea why?

[I have another question that's related to this one in here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836779/opencv-flannbasedmatcher-knnmatch)

UPDATED

This is basically the code I'm running

```
const Ptr<flann::IndexParams>& indexParams=new flann::KDTreeIndexParams(4);
const Ptr<flann::SearchParams>& searchParams=new flann::SearchParams(64);
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher>   matcher = new cv::FlannBasedMatcher(indexParams,  searchParams);
matcher->clear();
std::vector<Anakin::RichImg*>* patterns = loadPatterns();
std::vector<cv::Mat> pdescriptors(patterns->size());
for (int i = 0; i < patterns->size();i++){
    RichImg* p = patterns->at(i);
    pdescriptors.at(i) = p->getDescriptors();
}
this->detector->add(pdescriptors);
this->detector->train();
std::vector< std::vector<cv::DMatch> > m_knnMatches;
const cv::Mat& queryDescriptors = getSceneDescriptors();
if (queryDescriptors.empty()) return;
if(queryDescriptors.type()!=CV_32F) {
    queryDescriptors.convertTo(queryDescriptors, CV_32F);
}
matcher->knnMatch(queryDescriptors, m_knnMatches, 3);
for (size_t i=0; i<m_knnMatches.size(); i++) {
    const cv::DMatch& match_0 = m_knnMatches[i][0];
    const cv::DMatch& match_1 = m_knnMatches[i][1];
    const cv::DMatch& match_2 = m_knnMatches[i][2];
    std::cout << "match_0 : imgIdx(" << match_0.imgIdx << ") distance(" << match_0.distance << ")" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "match_1 : imgIdx(" << match_1.imgIdx << ") distance(" << match_1.distance << ")" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "match_2 : imgIdx(" << match_2.imgIdx << ") distance(" << match_2.distance << ")" << std::endl;

}
```

And results are:

```
match_0 : imgIdx(403) distance(0)
match_1 : imgIdx(1403) distance(0)
match_2 : imgIdx(1145) distance(0.224424)
match_0 : imgIdx(403) distance(0)
match_1 : imgIdx(1403) distance(0)
match_2 : imgIdx(1098) distance(0.270127)
match_0 : imgIdx(403) distance(0)
match_1 : imgIdx(1403) distance(0)
match_2 : imgIdx(1985) distance(0.227835)
```

NOTE: I just posted a lighter version of my code (the code needed to understand what I'm doing) and the result is just a part of what I get (original result have 800+ lines)

Comment: I think we would need to see some actual code as well as a little more context in order to help with either issue.

Comment: I just updated the question with some code and results